# Why didn't Jesse consider using the dangerous chemicals around him to escape?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

When Jesse was imprisoned in *Breaking Bad*, it does not look like he considered using the dangerous chemicals he had access to as a weapon or to assist in his escape: for example, he could have simply weakened his chains with HF acid although it is possible he did not have access to this but at Fring's lab they did have HF and I wonder if they had it because it is part of the process for producing meth.

Certainly White would have been someone who would have within a couple of days have injured or killed one of his captors (probably Todd) using chemicals -- was this just something the writers deliberately left out in Jesse's case for plot reasons or is it a way of demonstrating Jess's limitations?

I would add that the advantage to weakening his chains is this would be easier to hide than picking the lock which he eventually did; if he weakened the chains he could unexpectedly attack one of his captors although it seems like they avoid getting close to him most of the time.

Comment: Jesse wasn't a genius chemist, Walt was.

Comment: *Does HF dissolve metal?* Hydrofluoric acid is corrosive and ***readily* destroys tissue and bone**. HF ***readily* penetrates human skin**, allowing it to destroy soft tissues underneath and to decalcify bone (hypocalcemea). HF is ***moderately* corrosive to metals** and will dissolve glass – hydrofluoric acid must not be stored in glass bottles. – https://ehs.ucsc.edu/lab-safety-manual/specialty-chemicals/hydrofluoric-acid.html - No thanks, I'll wait.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember Jesse was an ok meth cook, his product was never as pure as Walter's. He wasn't a great chemist, Mr. White flunked him in his chemistry class.

So maybe he wouldn't know how to improvise an escape like that.

We also don't know the day-to-day of his captivity, maybe there were more goons keeping guard, maybe he was too afraid of getting shot trying to escape, it's just not explained in the series.

Comment: This, and also after Jesse's escape attempt, Todd shot Andrea then told Jesse: "there is still the kid"

Comment: Worth noting that as far as cooking meth goes, Walter explicitly tells Jesse that Jesse's meth is as good as Walter's when Jesse is in the hospital during "One Minute".

Comment: @MrNick but didn't Walter just say that to get Jesse back working with / for him? And to stop Jesse from pressing charges against the DEA?

Comment: You could make an argument for that but I didn't interpret it as Walter lying so much as just dropping his ego to appeal to Jesse. His cooks might not literally reach Walter's purity because his is as high as they can even measure, but Jesse cooks that batch for the cartel at 96.2% purity not long after the hospital scene and of course his solo product within the next year has people thinking it's Heisenberg.

Comment: "maybe he wouldn't know how to improvise an escape like that" — he absolutely wouldn't know. He knows the Heisenberg method back-to-front, but it doesn't seem like he's picked up any chemistry knowledge outside of that: as he says to Fring in Mexico, he identifies one of the chemicals via the "B" on the barrel.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Minor point, it is literally the insect bee that we see on the barrels. Don't know if that is the emblem of a company or the specific chemical -- I am guessing the former.

Comment: @releseabe: I thought that too at first, then I thought naw come on, sure that ain't a bee. Maybe I overthought it.

Comment: You can certainly see the insect on the barrel.